# The src drawable doesn't show up in the screen

Tags: android, android-imageview

I use a CircularImageView to set the profile picture of the person. For some reason, I couldn't figure out why the placeholder for the image is not showing up in the profile screen. When the user doesn't have any profile image set, the placeholder for the image doesn't show up at all. But when I set an image using the Camera or gallery intent in the same page, it shows the image in the placeholder. I am clueless in finding out what is the issue. Please help me why it is not displaying the default src attribute, when the user doesn't have any image in the profile CircularImageView.

Posting the xml file below.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.project.group.projectga.fragments.ProfileFragment">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileBackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_background"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photoCircle">

            <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton

                android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
                style="@style/fancyButtonProfile"
                app:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:fb_radius="30dp"
                app:fb_text="Camera"
                app:fb_textSize="15sp" />

            <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                android:id="@+id/galleryButton"
                style="@style/fancyButtonProfile"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cameraButton"
                app:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:fb_radius="30dp"
                app:fb_text="Gallery"
                app:fb_textSize="15sp" />

            <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                android:id="@+id/removeButton"
                style="@style/fancyButtonProfile"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/galleryButton"
                app:fb_borderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:fb_borderWidth="2dp"
                app:fb_defaultColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:fb_radius="30dp"
                app:fb_text="Remove"
                app:fb_textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/photoCircle"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/circularPhoto"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
                app:civ_shadow="true"
                app:civ_shadow_radius="24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/aboutDividerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photoLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aboutDivider"
            android:layout_width="336dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_300"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aboutLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/md_light_background"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/aboutLabel"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is an image, when the user is created for the first time.

[image: First Time user profile]

This is after a profile picture is set after the image is set using gallery.

[image: After image is set using Gallery Intent]

Thanks a lot in advance and any help is appreciated. This is where I load the picture in the fragment

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(profile.getProfile()).error(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp).into(circularProfilePhoto);
```

Comment: Maybe has something to do with width and height being 0?
If it's not that why don't you add a default person and change it when the user takes a photo?

Comment: If it is with the width and height, it will not show when I set the image too from gallery and camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to show the default image then you can set the default image from the code in your Activity/Fragment:

```
findViewById(R.id.circularPhoto).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chrysanthemum)
```

or

```
android:background = "@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
```

attribute in xml.

I don't understand why the image is not shown in xml even though you've used the **android** namespace with **src** attribute for showing drawable. If it would've been other namespace then aapt consider it as a custom attribute. I tried to show a default image in my code with **android:src** attribute and it worked.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/circularImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/chrysanthemum"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

But this one didn't work in xml, rather I need to set the image from the code to make it work:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/circularImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:src="@drawable/chrysanthemum"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Prashanth - I had to set it in the fragment, I don't seriously understand why it didn't load from the xml. Thanks!